# Including a model within a model, I think?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am extremely new to ASP/MVC3/C# but currently undertaking a project that requires me to list all the users in the database as a drop down list, ideally I want to filter this so that it only shows users in certain roles (i.e. either Admin, Staff or Student).

However my problem lies in the following, I have a controller (Requests.cs) with a method that does the following, and allows me to go to `http://server/Requests/UserList`:

```
    public ActionResult UserList()
    {
        // Create our view model
        var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
        var model = new StudentListViewModel
        {

            Users = users.OfType<MembershipUser>().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {

                Value = x.ProviderUserKey.ToString(),
                Text = x.UserName
            })
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

A view model that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AcademicRegistry.ViewModels
{
    public class StudentListViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "select user")]
        public string SelectedUser { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the relevant view:

```
@model AcademicRegistry.ViewModels.StudentListViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedUser)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUser, Model.Users)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

All of these work fine (in fact this is all code I found from another post on here) and this view displays what I want, i.e. a dropdown list with the value set to the userId and the text displayed as the username.

However I want this to be displayed within a different view, namely EditUser, however this already has a model associated with it (@model AcademicRegistry.Models.Requests):

```
@model AcademicRegistry.Models.Requests 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Requests</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
             *Wanting the dropdown list to show here*
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

I was wondering if anyone knew how I would go about having my drop down show where it needs to? This dropdown will be used on quite a few pages so ideally needs to be re-usable, and as I mentioned filtered to only show users that fall in to the 3 roles I have setup.

Comment: How are you navigating to the other views? Are they PartialView? Do  you redirect through another controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to place the code that currently gets the list of users and creates the SelectListItem list into a seperate method that other controllers can access.

You would then add the Users property to the ViewModels that will be displaying this list:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
```

So at this point, you have the list that you need to display. You can then either create a user control that takes the list and renders it, or just use the built-in DropDownList as you currently have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedUser, Model.Users)
```